# Should RouteConfig.cs be static class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

By Defualt, when you create a new ASP.Net MVC app, the RouteConfig is not a static class but the only method it has "RegisterRoutes" is a static method.

When I analyse my code using SonarQube, the tool suggests the following for RouteConfig.cs

Add a "protected" constructor or the "static" keyword to the class declaration

So, should I make the class static?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether the class is static or not will not change the behavior of the application. So if it is for making your code analysis tool happy, go ahead, make it static.